# DPL not being offset properly

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to get a DPL template to offset using a parameter in the URL, as described throughout "semeb. com/ dpldemo/ index. php?title=DPL:Manual" (remove spaces; I couldn't add in the link properly) and it is working.  Well, when I say working, it works for the first offset after publishing the template page, but then stops updating after that.  How can I make the DPL list update each time a new offset parameter is set in the URL rather than just staying at the same initial offset?  See live examples [here](http://drwho.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Answered_questions?DPL_offset=1000) and [here](http://drwho.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Category:The_Doctor?DPL_offset=200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  It was because the cache had been enabled by default to lessen the loads on the servers, but meant that the offset was being cached along with everything else.  Removing the cache fixed the problem, although introduced the new problem of not having results cached.  But that's a problem for another day.